# i have write password list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have `text.write(pas[n],pas[m])` in the `for` loop, but it doesn't work and throws an error:

```
    text = open('amir','w')
tedad = int(input('enter number : '))
pas = []
for i in range(1,tedad):
    b=input("enter: ")
    pas.append(b)

print('this is yuor pas {}' . format(pas))
ted = len(pas)

for d in range(1,ted):
    text.write(pas[d])

for n in range(1,ted):
    for m in range(1,ted):
        text.write(pas[n],pas[m])

for t in range(1,ted):
    for k in range(1,ted):
        for h in range(1,ted):
            text.write(pas[t],pas[k],pas[h])

for u in range(1,ted):
    for y in range(1,ted):
        for o in range(1,ted):
            for q in range(1,ted):
                text.write(pas[u],pas[y],pas[o],pas[q])
```

This should return an answer but it won't work.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please refactor your code into [mcve]

Comment: what is the desired behaviour?

Comment: `len(pas)` will always be 1. `pas` is a list containing a string. your loops will never do anything. why not just `past = input(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your desired output but here is a short refactor to make this code work

```
text = open('amir','w')
tedad = int(input('enter number : '))
pas = []
for i in range(1,tedad):
    b=input("enter: ")
    pas.append(b)

print('this is yuor pas {}' . format(pas))
ted = len(pas)

for d in range(1,ted):
    text.write("{}\n".format(pas[d]))

for n in range(1,ted):
    for m in range(1,ted):
        text.write("{},{}\n".format(pas[n],pas[m]))

for t in range(1,ted):
    for k in range(1,ted):
        for h in range(1,ted):
            text.write("{} {} {}\n".format(pas[t],pas[k],pas[h]))

for u in range(1,ted):
    for y in range(1,ted):
        for o in range(1,ted):
            for q in range(1,ted):
                text.write("{} {} {} {}\n".format(pas[u],pas[y],pas[o],pas[q]))
```

Answer (score -1):

The `text.write(str)` method does only take one argument. If you want to write multiple arguments you have to concatenate them first: `text.write(pas[n] + pas[m])`